# Python arcade: Add icon image to the side of the toolbar

Tags: python, arcade

Is there a way to add an icon to the toolbar? I developed a bit of branding for my game at compilation; however, I would also like to add it to the window

[image: toolbar]

Comment: if you can't find information in `Arcade` documentation then you may try in `pyglet` documentation because `Arcade` uses `pyglet` to create window - and I think it should have some function to set icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking in the future, @furas's comment was correct. There is a pyglet function `set_icon` that is an undocumented member function of `arcade.Window`. So after `super.__init__...`

```
from pyglet.image import load as pyglet_load
self.set_icon(pyglet_load(icon_file))
```